# "ifconfig" gives an error on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, bash, ifconfig, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try using the command "ifconfig" on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows(WSL), it gives me an error like this :-

> root@example:~# **ifconfig**
> **Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.**

And when I try to run "iwconfig" :-

> eth0        no wireless extensions.
>
> wifi0      no wireless extensions.
>
> lo           no wireless extensions.
>
> und0       no wireless extensions.
>
> und1       no wireless extensions.

This leads me to believe that it hasn't detected the network devices, but then how is the internet working? Internet works well, as I've used *apt-get* to install apps;

I'm no linux pro, let alone a wsl pro, so could I have a  some advice on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: The Bash implementation on Windows is not fully featured, and many networking related parts of the kernel are not currently implemented.

Comment: @MarkoPolo Have to agree with that, that's why its still a beta feature.

Answer (score 3):

WSL doesn't run a full Linux kernel – it only translates each individual syscall to its Windows variant. Therefore WSL doesn't *need* to "detect" devices the same way real Linux would, because Windows itself has already done that.

Besides, "detecting" a device is not the same thing as exposing information about it, anyway. The files in `/proc/net` are only for informative purposes; they are not needed for actually using the net. So it's not a big problem if they are missing.

In addition, **most network programs *do not care* about the actual devices;** they only deal with high-level functions (BSD sockets) and let the OS handle the details. Therefore, as long as WSL implements functions like `socket()` and `connect()` and `sendto()`, that's enough.

---

The situation with `iwconfig` is similar: the wireless devices are *already* managed by Windows itself; WSL just doesn't know how to translate the link information to Linux programs, but most of them do not need to know that anyway.

Besides, `iwconfig` is an old tool that uses the nearly-obsolete WEXT API. I suspect the developers would care more about making modern nl80211-based tools such as **`iw`** work first.

(Even many Linux drivers no longer support WEXT directly – they only emulate it on top of nl80211.)

Comment: Hmmm, I see. How do I do stuff like advanced network monitoring if WSL doesn't even detect the network connections/adapters? I've upvoted, but let me see if anyone else answers before accepting.

Comment: Either use native Windows programs (want tcpdump? use Wireshark) or wait until Microsoft improves the WSL subsystem (e.g. see [issue 66](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/66), [issue 239](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/239)).